# Grill in Solidworks

Tags: solidworks

I'm a beginner with Solidworks and I'm trying to model the grill in the bellow picture. So far I have the outer frame which I have sketched on the Top Plane, then I created a new plane as a copy of the Right Plane in order to do a profile of one of the grill wires. However, I can not Linear Pattern this as the wire plane is different from the Top Plain.

I've followed the tutorial Oven Rack tutorial on YouTube (https://youtu.be/eBC6t_muKNU), but this uses an Extruded Boss to create the wires and thus they are straight and are created on the same plane as can be patterned. However, the wires in the picture have bends and connect to the frame underneath.

So the question is how do I create this picture where the wires have bends and once I've created one, how do I use a pattern to create the other wires?

[image: Grill]

Answer (score 1):

You can do all this in one 3D Sketch, but in general it's easier to do it in separate sketches and features. This is because it will be easier to reuse your design and pattern/suppress/unsuppress some features.

The approach I'm using is with separate 2D Sketches and features.

To draw the curved grill wires you will need another plane to draw your sketch onto.
Let's say your outer frame uses a sketch on the top plane, then you will need a plane perpendicular to the top plane for instance: the Front plane (or a parallel plane to the Front Plane)

then you can sketch on that plane. Use the sketch with a structural member(weldment) or a sweep,... Here is a quick result using structural member, not to scale and not complete to show the essentials. The same can be achieved using sweep but you will need another sketch for the section in that case or use the circular option (see picture above)
[image: sweep circular profile]
[image]

Tip: make tangent constraints on the arcs.

Then you can pattern the bodiesor feature using a sketch line from the outer wire as direction. In the image below you can see the structure of the SolidWorks file: first the outer frame, then the curved frame and then wire2. which are the patterned (I named them resp. outerframe, curved and wire2 in the object tree to make it clear)
[image]